# How to set passhprase for USB volume forever with windows dialog in Ubuntu?

Tags: encryption, gnome-keyring, passphrase

I have an encrypted USB device, till recently the passphrase was saved with the option 'Remember forever'. However, accidentally I removed it the volume without unmounting it. Ever since that I have to provide the passphrase each time the system starts up. I no longer get the option to remove the passphrase forever. How can I access that window, so that the passphrase can be set forever?